# Compare mscrm GUIDs in js

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, guid

Is there some better/official way, how to compare CRM 2011 GUIDs in JavaScript

```
2e9565c4-fc5b-e211-993c-000c29208ee5=={2E9565C4-FC5B-E211-993C-000C29208EE5}
```

without using `.replace()` and `.toLowerCase()`?

First one is got thru XMLHttpRequest/JSON:

```
JSON.parse(r.responseText).d.results[0].id
```

Second one is got from form:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("field").getValue()[0].id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official way to compare GUIDs in JavaScript because there is no primitive GUID type. Thus you should treat GUIDs as strings.

If you must not use `replace()` and `toLowerCase()` you can use a regular expression:

```
// "i" is for ignore case
var regExp = new RegExp("2e9565c4-fc5b-e211-993c-000c29208ee5", "i"); 

alert(regExp.test("{2E9565C4-FC5B-E211-993C-000C29208EE5}"));
```

It would probably be slower than replace/toLowerCase().

Comment: replace() and toLowerCase() are not forbidden, but it didn't appeared to me right; I would expect MS provides some method in SDK, when CRM returns the same GUID in two different forms.
Your solution with regex seems to me like a little bit more clear code.

Answer (score 2):

```
var rgx = /[\{\-\}]/g;
function _guidsAreEqual(left, right) {
    var txtLeft = left.replace(rgx, '').toUpperCase();
    var txtRight = right.replace(rgx, '').toUpperCase();
    return txtLeft === txtRight;
};
```

Comment: The functions removes separators and performs case insensitive comparison after that. Regex may be placed inside function's body.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the node-uuid (https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid) library and do a byte comparison after parsing the strings into bytes. The bytes are returned as arrays and can be compared using the lodash _.difference method. This will handle cases where the GUID's aren't using the same case or if they don't have '-' dashes.

Coffeescript:

```
compareGuids: (guid1, guid2) ->
    bytes1 = uuid.parse(guid1)
    bytes2 = uuid.parse(guid2)
    # difference returns [] for equal arrays
    difference = _.difference(bytes1, bytes2)
    return difference.length == 0
```

Javascript (update):

```
compareGuids: function(guid1, guid2) {
    var bytes1, bytes2, difference;
    bytes1 = uuid.parse(guid1);
    bytes2 = uuid.parse(guid2);
    difference = _.difference(bytes1, bytes2);
    return difference.length === 0;
  }
```

Comment: I would prefer the code sample in JS and information to download the other library, but I made it working and it works fine. It seems complicated for a quick use on a CRM form, but can be neat for large projects. Thanks!